# mysql how to count occuraces of specific time in a given period

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count occurrences of 9AM between a given period say 10th April 9PM(admission_date) to 14th April 8AM(discharge_date). I am able to calculate the total days & hours between the two dates, but have no idea how I can count such occurrences.

Looking for some help here.

Comment: You should probably list some details of your table schemas, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: You could just use a WHERE clause to solve this. Like so: `SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE admission_date >= 1stDate AND discharge_date <= 2ndDate`. Assuming, of course, that you're using a date format for the columns.

Comment: @The42ndDoctor - Thanks but count(*) how it will count concurrences of 9 AM with that query, can you kindly elaborate.

Comment: This does not take into consideration 9am.

Comment: @The42ndDoctor - No I am looking for say how many times 9AM occurred between the two dates.

Comment: @Joshi Okay, I misread this a bit. You're looking only for instances of 9 AM then. In that case, you would use a DATEPART `WHERE HOUR(admission_date) = 09 OR HOUR(discharge_date) = 09`

Comment: I think still there is some confusion - it is the occurrence of 9AM between `admission_date` & `discharge_date`. so `hour(admission_date)` cannot return the count of 9AM between the two dates.

Comment: @Joshi Perhaps something like this then: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE (HOUR(admission_date) = 09 OR HOUR(discharge_date) = 09) AND admission_date >= 1stDate AND discharge_date <= 2ndDate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the number of days and then deduct 1 if the admission is after 9am and deduct another if the discharge is before 9am.

```
SELECT 1+DATEDIFF(discharge_date,admission_date)-IF(TIME(admission_date)>'09:00:00',1,0)-IF(TIME(discharge_date)<'09:00:00',1,0) AS COUNT_OF_9AM
FROM table
```

Comment: I applied ur query, but it is counting one less than the actual. where there is 3 occurances it is counting 2 and where there is one it is counting 0. Looks like it needs some little alteration

Comment: Sorry, you need to add one since date diff is the difference and won't include the current 9am! I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you want to count the occurrences of 9AM between date1 and date2. You can write a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE time = 9AM and DATE BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

P.S. Please provide your database table schema for a better answer.